# Read file preserving linebreaks and spaces

Tags: php, arrays

I'm writing a PHP script which stores the values in the file in an array. I want newlines and spaces to be preserved.

The text file looks like below:

```
abc

pqr

xyz
```

What I thought is to use `cat` Linux command to read the file and then direct it's value in an array.

This is what I tried:

```
$input = '/var/www/oj/1.in';
$array = system(cat $input);
```

That didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you reading the value? (Since newlines won't show without `<pre>` tags around them)

Comment: So you want to convert the `.in` file to an array of `[ 'abc', '', 'pqr', '', 'xyz' ]` - is that right?

Comment: Did you do any research before asking this question? A basic search for `php read file into array` would have given you the answer to this question.

Comment: not exactly that .
i want in into 'abc\npqr\nxyz\n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the function that is used for this:

```
$array = file($input);
print_r($array);
```

But since you don't actually want an array as stated in the question, try:

```
$output = file_get_contents($input);
```

Or to skip the empty lines:

```
$output = implode(file($input, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
```

Comment: Really?  That's very descriptive.

Comment: actually i want array to contain "abc\npqr\nxyz\n"

Comment: So no array?  Edited.